# How to boot the system in cgroup v2 mode?

Tags: docker

I used the following commands to install docker in rootless mode.

```
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
systemctl --user start docker.service
systemctl --user enable docker.service
sudo loginctl enable-linger blueray
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=+ep ~/bin/rootlesskit
```

Now when I ran `docker info`, it says:

```
WARNING: Running in rootless-mode without cgroups. To enable cgroups in rootless-mode, you need to boot the system in cgroup v2 mode.
```

What should I do to fix this warning?

Comment: What distribution are you running? Some recent distributions (e.g, Fedora >= 34 (maybe earlier) use cgroups v2 by default). If you need to explicitly enable it, a search for "<your dsitribution> enable cgroups v2" will probably find what you need. https://rootlesscontaine.rs/getting-started/common/cgroup2/ is probably sufficient.

Comment: I am using Linux Mint 20.2